# php specify folder from select option

Tags: php, forms, file, post

Sorry I am new to PHP. I want to create a form for getting the destination of a page that is being created as filename & foldername.

What I've done so far:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type='text' name='filename' placeholder='Enter a filename' />
    <select>
        <option> value='Folder1' name="thisfolder">Folder1</option>
        <option> value='Folder2' name="thisfolder">Folder2</option>
        <option> value='Folder3' name="thisfolder">Folder3</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Run the Script' />
</form>

<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){ 
        $filename=$_POST['filename'];
        $myFile = .$thisfolder. "/page" .$filename.".php";

        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
        $stringData = "Hello";
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    } 
?>
```

As you've noticed first `input` is used to get the target page's filename & the `select` element is used to choose one of the three predefined folders as the storage directory destination.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type='text' name='filename' placeholder='Enter a filename'>
    <select name="thisfolder">
        <option value="Folder1">Folder1</option>
        <option value="Folder2">Folder2</option>
        <option value="Folder3">Folder3</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Run the Script'>
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    // the name of the file to create
    $filename=$_POST['filename'];
    // the name of the folder to put $filename in
    $thisFolder = $_POST['thisfolder'];
    // make sure #thisFolder of actually a folder
    if (!is_dir(__DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder)) {
        // if not, we need to make a new folder
        mkdir(__DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder);
    }
    // . . . /[folder name]/page[file name].php
    $myFile = __DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder. "/page" .$filename.".php";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
    $stringData = "Hello";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
}
?>
```

Comment: i am having this error Notice: Undefined variable: thisfolder in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\page1.php on line 26

Comment: look dear, Folder1, Folder2 and Folder3 these are my folders. i want to be able to select one of those folders where i want my page to be created. i don't want to have default folder

Comment: PHP is case sensitive. change both variable occurrences to `$thisfolder`.

Comment: i get `Notice: Undefined variable: thisfolder in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\page1.php on line 27` and it creates the page at root folder instead of the folder that i selected

Comment: @BehradKhodayar which variable dear

Comment: @BehradKhodayar Thanks, that was a typo. This has been tested and works now

Comment: @MmPp My pleasure. Glad I could help.

Comment: dear @JustinTaddei please check my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42541770/getting-php-as-text-on-output/42542238?noredirect=1#comment72220448_42542238 you helped me with this code yesterday

Comment: @JustinTaddei one question bro. how much would you ask if i want to learn javascript and php from you ? i only know a little bit on editting

Comment: @MmPp, let's talk here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137005/learning-javascript-and-php

Comment: bro can i have chat with you ? if you have time

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a name to the drop down menu like so also the select menu is inverted select on outside nest options within

```
<select name='myFolder'>
```

then on form submit you can call the param using `$_POST['myFolder']` and echo it out in the path spot - also you will wont to create a var so you can set a default if nothing is selected like this.

```
$myfolder = $_POST['myFolder'] ? $_POST['myFolder'] : 'your defualt folder';
```

below is a working example of what it should look like,

```
<form method="post">
<input type='text' name='filename' placeholder='Enter a filename'>
<input type='submit' value='Run the Script'>
<select name='myFolder'>
<option value="Folder1">Folder1</option>
<option value="Folder2">Folder2</option>
<option value="Folder3">Folder3</option>
</select>
</form>

<?php
 // store the myfolder param
  $thisfolder = $_POST['myFolder'] ? $_POST['myFolder'] : 'Folder1';

  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
  { 

  $filename=$_POST['filename']; 
  $myFile = $thisfolder. "/page_" .$filename.".php";

  $stringData = "Hello";
    if (!mkdir($thisfolder, 0777, true)){
        // creat directory if not already
        }
  if(file_put_contents($myFile, $stringData)){
  echo 'File Saved!';
 }else{
  echo 'no directory exists'; 
 }} 
?>
```

Comment: dear your code didn't i am sure i have lots o mistakes in my code but you edited the code without testing it

Comment: I deleted the extra period - sorry didn't have a way to test it at the moment, but explanation is correct