# getting php as text on output

Tags: php, html

first of all this is my php code. i am trying to get this code as text on output. not sure how i do that. with html we can do `\"` to insert it inside php but how do i get this done like that on my code ?

```
<?php
$stringData = "

    // Start here

    <?php
    $width = $_GET['width'];
    $heigh = $_GET['height'];

        echo 'Hello';

    ?>
    // End here

    ";
?>
```

i have marked that part that i want to get it on output as text but when i put it like that on page i get syntax error not sure why.

EDIT #2

here below is my full code and i explain how my code works and for what.
my code is to create page and put something inside that page created

```
<form method="post">
    <label>Page Name:</label><br>
    <input type='text' name='filename' placeholder='page name'>
    <label>Folders</label>
    <select name="thisfolder">
        <option value="">Default</option>
        <option value="Folder1">Folder1</option>
        <option value="Folder2">Folder2</option>
        <option value="Folder3">Folder3</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <label>content</label><br>
    <input type='text' name='strin' placeholder='content of created page'>
    <input type='submit' value='Add Feed'>
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    // the name of the file to create
    $filename=$_POST['filename'];
    // the name of the file to be in page created
    $strin=$_POST['strin'];
    // the name of the folder to put $filename in
    $thisFolder = $_POST['thisfolder'];
    // make sure #thisFolder of actually a folder
    if (!is_dir(__DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder)) {
        // if not, we need to make a new folder
        mkdir(__DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder);
    }
    // . . . /[folder name]/page[file name].php
    $myFile = __DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder. "/page" .$filename.".php";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
    $stringData = "

    <?php
    $width = $_GET['width'];
    $heigh = $_GET['height'];

        echo '';

    ?>

    ";

    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
}
?>
```

what i am trying to do is, passing that php code that is inside `$stringData` to that page that will be created

Comment: You don't echo the variables in there, but if you did `eval($stringData);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to escape the `$`'s in your text.

Set `$stringData` like this:

```
$stringData = "

// Start here

<?php
\$width = \$_GET['width'];
\$heigh = \$_GET['height'];

    echo 'Hello';

?>
// End here

";
```

Comment: can you please ecit my code and show me how ? in your answer

Comment: the code with php star and close tags that is between start here and end here must be as text

Comment: Just did, if it works, please set it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: please check my question i have added EDIT #2 with full code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137000/discussion-between-jediburrell-and-mm-pp).

Comment: one question bro. how much would you ask if i want to learn javascript and php from you ? i only know a little bit on editting

Comment: you there bro . i need a little help if you can just send me chat request

Comment: @MmPp Email me.

Comment: i have emailed you bro and didn't get replay yet

Answer (score 1):

using [highlight_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php) internal function

```
echo highlight_string($stringData);
```

or using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars/)

```
echo htmlspecialchars($stringData);
```

**EDIT , as long as you don't want to print the php code literally to the output [as you've mentioned in your comment]**

the problem here is that you are using (double quotes) to store values, which has special meaning in php

the solution is to store your text in single quotes ,

```
<?php
$stringData = '

    // Start here

    <?php
    $width = $_GET["width"];
    $heigh = $_GET["height"];

        echo "Hello";

    ?>
    // End here

    ';
?>
```

Comment: dear edit my code in your answer so i can understand. i don't know much on php

Comment: @MmPp you want to print the php code written in `$stringData` string as plain text output ??

Comment: please check my question i have added EDIT #2 with full code

Comment: how could be , check out https://3v4l.org/TA2MO , the code executes the echo after the code , which is mean that variable declaration was right

Comment: thanks or your time dear but @JediBurrell has fixed it for me and that was just ading `\` before each dollar sign

Answer (score 1):

You're using double quotes (`"`) which lets you use `$variables` inside the string where single quotes (`'`) will not.

like so:

```
$color = 'red';  

$string_one = "My car is $color."
echo $string_one; // My car is red.

$string_two = 'My car is $color.'
echo $string_two; // My car is $color.
```

So to fix your code you simply need to change the double quotes to single quotes (and escape [put a backslash before] the other single quotes).
Like so:

```
<?php
$stringData = '

    // Start here

    <?php
    $width = \$_GET[\'width\'];
    $heigh = \$_GET[\'height\'];

        echo \'Hello\';

    ?>
    // End here

    ';
?>
```

Comment: thanks aa lot dear for your time and answer but @JediBurrell has fixed it. and yes as you mintioned `escape [put a backslash before]` that was the problem

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: i just posted the code on chat with explanation bro

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
?>
    // End here must be in out put

    ";
?>
```

There is not start php delimiter `<?php`

Correct is:

```
?>
    // End here must be in out put
<?php
    ";
?>
```

You missed one more php delimiter, total 2:

```
<?php
$stringData = "
**?>**
    // Start here must be in out put
    <?php
    $width = $_GET['width'];
    $heigh = $_GET['height'];

        echo '';

    ?>
    // End here must be in out put
**<?php**
    ";
?>
```

Comment: i updated code you see it says start here - end here

Comment: look dear. i don't know much in php but this `$stringData` called variable right ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code I added:

```
<?php
$stringData = '

    // Start here

    <?php
    $width = $_GET["width"];
    $heigh = $_GET["height"];

        echo "Hello";

    ?>
    // End here

    ';

    echo $stringData;
?>
```

When I opened this phap page, I had in browser:

// Start here // End here

In Page Source View I had:

```
// Start here

    <?php
    $width = $_GET["width"];
    $heigh = $_GET["height"];

        echo "Hello";

    ?>
    // End here
```

There is no error! I see now what you wont.

Answer (score 0):

This code with "(string) $price" working:

```
<?php
$price = 10;

$stringData = "start here (string) $price end here";

echo $stringData;

echo "(string) $price";

?>
```